# How do I run apply on a data.table?

Tags: r, apply, data.table

I have a `data.table` with columns 2 through 20 as strings with spaces (e.g., "Species Name"). I want to run `str_replace()` on all those columns simultaneously so all the "Species Name" become "Species_Name".  I can either do:

```
data.table(apply(as.data.frame(dt[,2:dim(dt)[2], with=F]), 2, 
                               function(x){ str_replace(x," ","_") }))
```

or if I keep it as a `data.table` object, then I can do this one column at a time:

```
dt[,SpeciesName := str_replace(SpeciesName, " ", "_")
```

How do I do this for all columns 2 through the end similar to the one of the above?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Completely rewritten on 2015-11-24, to fix an error in previous versions.**

**Also added more modern options on 2019-09-27**

You have a few options.

1. Process all of the target columns with an embedded call to
   `lapply()`, using `:=` to assign the modified values in place. This
   relies on `:=`'s very handy support for simultaneous assignment to several column named on its LHS.
2. Use a `for` loop to run through the target columns one at a time,
   using `set()` to modify the value of each one in turn.
3. Use a `for` loop to iterate over multiple "naive" calls
   to `[.data.table()`, each one of which modifies a single column.

These methods all seem about equally fast, so which one you use will
be mostly a matter of taste. (1) is nicely compact and
expressive. It's what I most often use, though you may find (2)
easier to read. Because they process and modify the columns one at a time, (2) or (3) will have an advantage in the rare situation in which your data.table is so large that you are in danger of running up against limits
imposed by your R session's available memory.

```
library(data.table)

## Create three identical 1000000-by-20 data.tables
DT1 <- data.table(1:1e6,
           as.data.table(replicate(1e6, paste(sample(letters, nr, TRUE),
                                             sample(letters, nr, TRUE)))))
cnames <- c("ID", paste0("X", 1:19))
setnames(DT1, cnames)
DT2 <- copy(DT1); DT3 <- copy(DT1)

## Method 1
system.time({
DT1[, .SDcols=cnames[-1L], cnames[-1L] := 
  lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub(" ", "_", x, fixed=TRUE)), ]
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  10.90    0.11   11.06 

## Method 2
system.time({
    for(cname in cnames[-1]) {
        set(DT2, j=cname, value=gsub(" ", "_", DT2[[cname]], fixed=TRUE))
    }
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  10.65    0.05   10.70 

## Method 3
system.time({
    for(cname in cnames[-1]) {
        DT3[ , (cname) := gsub(" ", "_", get(cname), fixed=TRUE)]
    }
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  10.33    0.03   10.37
```

For more details on `set()` and `:=`, read their help page, gotten by typing `?set` or `?":="`.

Comment: This is an interesting case. Here, 19 columns out of 20 are being replaced; the RHS of `:=` is almost all the table. The advantage of `:=` is greater when, say, one or two columns are added to 20, or one or two columns of 20 are modified. In those cases most of the columns are left in place and `:=` is much faster than copying the whole table.

Comment: Also, `set()` is a new function in v1.8.0 (not yet on CRAN) which provides `:=` functionality directly. `set()` can be much faster than `:=` when assigning within a loop (for easier more natural programming). There's an example in latest NEWS on homepage.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Thanks for your comments. They reminded me that, over the weekend, I'd had a nagging feeling about the answer I'd given here, and spurred me to revisit this. Obviously I had good reason to feel nagged. Please have a look at my revised answer. Also **please add any of the suggestions you've got in your comments to the text of my answer**, where you think they might help. I'll have a look at `set()`, but don't yet feel qualified to discuss it. And, once again, thanks for all of the  work you put into continuing development of the data.table package!

Comment: Aaah, that's better :-) If I could +2 I would. On the RHS of `:=` perhaps try `DT1[[cname]]` instead of `DT1[,cname,with=FALSE]`. `[[` doesn't copy (until write) so should be faster than `[.data.table` at whole column extract (untested guess).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I tried your suggestion of using `DT1[[cname]]`, and it was much *slower* than using `DT1[,cname,with=FALSE]`, basically as slow as my earlier `'lapply'` solution. Very interesting. I'll think about this, but if you have an idea of why that is, I'd be very curious to hear your thoughts. Cheers.

Comment: Ok just ran it. The `gsub` call is being passed a 1-column `data.table` in the example so it's fast but doesn't seem to be doing the right thing. That's an example where the `drop=TRUE` would come in handy, but in the meantime have to add `[[1]]` afterwards. Also the `DT1 <- DT2 <- DT3` wouldn't actually copy on write, may need to be `DT1 <- copy(DT2) <- copy(DT3)`, although the example doesn't seem to use those.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- OK, I incorporated both of those changes, and redid the timings. It all looks good now, and is hopefully a useful reference for others. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem right. The `DT1[[cname]][[1]]` is getting the first item only which may be why it's so fast, then `:=` is recycling that down the column. It appears to work in this case because the example is the same string. Should be just `DT1[[cname]]` then it'll be the correct (slower) speed.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I agree that this isn't right, but I'm all turned around re: what the best method is. I think I should revert this to my original answer, where it was at revision 6, after you made the minor edit correcting the the data.table version I referenced from 1.7.10 to 1.7.8. Please advise me on this, and I'll perform the rollback or otherwise edit the post. (Seems like the takehome here is that being able to put multiple columns on the LHS of `:=` can be useful, but not so much if you are replacing nearly all of the columns).

Comment: Yes that's the takehome (my first comment above as it turns out ;)) However, there are still two big advantages of multiple `LHS`: i) _deleting_ many columns (instantly) using `:=NULL` and ii) if the 20 column table is 50GB in RAM then looping `:=` by column will only need one column's worth of working memory at a time to get the job done, whereas an `lapply`'d `RHS` needs a full copy (maybe even two full copies) and may well return the dreaded `out of memory` error.

Comment: Defining DT1 returns an error: `DT1 <- data.table(1:1e6,
+            as.data.table(replicate(1e6, paste(sample(letters, nr, TRUE),
+                                              sample(letters, nr, TRUE)))))
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  object 'nr' not found`

Comment: Proposed solution:  `DT1 <- data.table(1:1e6,
           as.data.table(replicate(19, paste(sample(letters, 2, TRUE),
                                             sample(letters, 2, TRUE)))))`

Comment: Sorry, what's `nr`? Code breaks on that when I try to run it

Comment: @Hack-R nr=20 deciphering the comments

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
library("stringr")
dt[, -1] <- lapply(dt[, -1], function(x) str_replace(x," ","_"))
```